# What can C++ developer use on Nokia N900 for capturing live audio from microphone?

Tags: c++, c, linux, audio, nokia

So I have G++ installed, I can esely [capture from main camera with OpenCV (at least 4 fps)](http://blog.mikeasoft.com/2010/06/17/gstreamer-opencv-plugins-on-the-nokia-n900/). But I also want to capture Live sound from mic. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [QT for Maemo](http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/maemo). It should handle the capturing part. Not sure about openCV though.

Comment: Could you point me to some microphone capturing samples, please.